# Trying to select the first empty cell in a range

Tags: excel, vba

OK I got selecting the first empty cell in a column. I'm trying to limit this to a range of cells in a column and for some reason it is escaping me. I've tried a number of different methods I found on here and it always seems to either error, post in the first cell of the range, or post in the first cell of the column.

I'm trying to click a button and have it copy a calculated number over to a recording area of the spreadsheet that I have designated. Essentially working on a machine that outputs numbers which we record, do some calculations with in stages, then it finally outputs a final number. We have to repeat this several times. So at the end I want to click a button and save that final number. The format of the spreadsheet is a pain and for internal reasons I can't change it. So essentially It's copying the value of I4 into the first available cell of Range L5:L19

Here's what I have sofar:

```
Private Sub RecordCalcOffset_Click()
     Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
     Dim currentRowValue As String

     sourceCol = 12
     rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row

     For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
          currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Value
          If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then
               Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Select
          End If
     Next
     Range("I4").Copy
     ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what i use, and it works, it should work for you but the enums  you should declare them.

Function sExcelDetermineLastColumnOfWorkSheet(oExcelInputRange As Excel.Range, _
Optional lLastColumnOfSheetEnum As Long = ExcelRangeEnum.LastColumnEqualToLastColumnOfWorksheet) As String
' MsgBox "inside sExcelDetermineLastColumnOfWorkSheet"
' brief, will determine what will be consider the last column of worksheet (either last column of entire worksheet, last column with text when looking in value or formulas and whether search will start at beginning or end of input range )
' created, 2017May1
' tested on, Win7, office 2010

Dim oExcelWS  As Excel.Worksheet
Dim sLastColumnLetter  As String
Dim lStartRow  As Long, lStartColumnLetterIndex  As Long, lLastColumnIndex As Long

Set oExcelWS = oExcelInputRange.Worksheet

' get start column letter and row  of range
lStartColumnLetterIndex = vExcelSelectCaseParseRangeAddress(oExcelInputRange, ExcelRangeEnum.GetStartColumnIndex)
lStartRow = vExcelSelectCaseParseRangeAddress(oExcelInputRange, ExcelRangeEnum.GetStartRowIndex)

' if we desire the last column of worksheet  then get it
If lLastColumnOfSheetEnum = ExcelRangeEnum.LastColumnEqualToLastColumnOfWorksheet Then
sLastColumnLetter = sConvertColumnNumber2Letter(lExcelLastColumnOfSheet(oExcelWS))

ElseIf lLastColumnOfSheetEnum = ExcelRangeEnum.LastColumnEqualLastColumnInRowWithTextWithLookInFormulaIfSearchFromStart Then
sLastColumnLetter = sConvertColumnNumber2Letter(iColumnLetterToNumber(sExcelGetNextEmptyOrBlankColumnLetterFromRowGivenStartRowAndColumnIndex(oExcelWS, lStartRow, lStartColumnLetterIndex, xlNext, xlFormulas)) - 1)

ElseIf lLastColumnOfSheetEnum = ExcelRangeEnum.LastColumnEqualLastColumnInRowWithTextWithLookInValueIfSearchFromStart Then
' MsgBox "inside LastColumnEqualLastColumnInRowWithTextWithLookInValueIfSearchFromStart "

' if last row of sheet is current cell (for example, 1,1, make sure it has a value in order to return it, else return nothing )
If iColumnLetterToNumber(sExcelGetNextEmptyOrBlankColumnLetterFromRowGivenStartRowAndColumnIndex(oExcelWS, lStartRow, lStartColumnLetterIndex, xlNext, xlValues)) > 1 Then
sLastColumnLetter = sConvertColumnNumber2Letter(iColumnLetterToNumber(sExcelGetNextEmptyOrBlankColumnLetterFromRowGivenStartRowAndColumnIndex(oExcelWS, lStartRow, lStartColumnLetterIndex, xlNext, xlValues)) - 1)
Else
sLastColumnLetter = sExcelGetNextEmptyOrBlankColumnLetterFromRowGivenStartRowAndColumnIndex(oExcelWS, lStartRow, lStartColumnLetterIndex, xlNext, xlValues)
End If

' MsgBox "answer =" & sLastColumnLetter
' last column with content (search formula or value) but start search from last column of entire worksheet
ElseIf lLastColumnOfSheetEnum = ExcelRangeEnum.LastColumnEqualLastColumnInRowWithTextWithLookInFormulaIfSearchFromEndOfWorkSheet Then
lLastColumnIndex = lExcelLastColumnOfSheet(oExcelWS)
sLastColumnLetter = sConvertColumnNumber2Letter(iColumnLetterToNumber(sExcelGetNextEmptyOrBlankColumnLetterFromRowGivenStartRowAndColumnIndex(oExcelWS, lStartRow, lLastColumnIndex, xlPrevious, xlFormulas)) - 1)

ElseIf lLastColumnOfSheetEnum = ExcelRangeEnum.LastColumnEqualLastColumnInRowWithTextWithLookInValueIfSearchFromEndOfWorkSheet Then

```
lLastColumnIndex = lExcelLastColumnOfSheet(oExcelWS)
If sExcelGetNextEmptyOrBlankColumnLetterFromRowGivenStartRowAndColumnIndex(oExcelWS, lStartRow, lLastColumnIndex, xlPrevious, xlValues) = vbNullString Then
sLastColumnLetter = sConvertColumnNumber2Letter(lLastColumnIndex)
Else
sLastColumnLetter = sConvertColumnNumber2Letter(iColumnLetterToNumber(sExcelGetNextEmptyOrBlankColumnLetterFromRowGivenStartRowAndColumnIndex(oExcelWS, lStartRow, lLastColumnIndex, xlPrevious, xlValues)) - 1)
End If
```

End If

sExcelDetermineLastColumnOfWorkSheet = sLastColumnLetter

' clean up
Set oExcelWS = Nothing
End Function

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).